# CUPS lose some job during printing

Tags: cups, printing

We are a public library, every time a user search a book on our web-opac and need to reserve it, the system send a reservation document (PDF) to a printer, that is in our libray warehouse, and everything works fine. During the night the printer is off. It is turned off at 7pm and turned on at 7am. During such period, all the pdf are sent to a CUPS queue. In the morning, when we turn on the printer, some of the nightly jobs are not printed.

We do not have errors, we can track every nighlty PDFs in our application log, in the /var/log/cups/page_log and find the correspondings files cNNNN in /var/spoll/cups. Every nightly document is correctly managed from CUPS, apparently, but some of these document are not printed, without a good reason.

How can I log the CUPS/printer dialog to debug that situation? Our printer does not have an internal log, it can only count pages. Anyway every morning I can see all the pages sent to the printer from page_log, but real pages are less and we need to re-print such jobs. That is annoying.

Sorry for my english, thanks to all